# Displaying bar legend for point data in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, legend

I often work with large point feature classes that I'm symbolizing with the full 32 classes of graduated colors.

**Is it possible to add a simple, horizontal color bar into the legend in such cases (as you might for a raster data)?**

This seems like something that other people must want to do, but I'm not seeing it in the *'Style...'* menu nor can I find in a search.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to do this is by using a dummy layer.

Create a raster or polygon layer (whichever will give you the type of legend you are wanting), add sample records to give the range, and add that to your Table of Contents, and turn off the layer so it doesn't draw.

Make the legend show that layer, and remove your other layer from the legend.  Set the legend to display layers that are not visible.